# Multiple NPM repos in one GitHub repo with scoping?

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

Let's say I have a client, `awesome-service` that composes of different types of services, `http-service`, `log-service`, etc...

I want to have the option of either including each individual service (and a specific version), or just require all of the `awesome-services`, so in effect I want something like:

```
const awesomeService = require('@awesome-service'); 
// Now awesomeService has
// awesomeService.httpService;
// awesomeService.logService;
// etc

// or individually
const httpService = require('@awesome-service/http-service');
```

Is this possible? What would the package.json and the GitHub organization look like? Maybe this is package.json?

```
"dependencies": {
   "awesome-service": "@awesome-service"
   // OR if individually importing them
   "http-service": "@awesome-service/http-service#1.0.0"
}
```

How can this be accomplished, or rather can this be accomplished?

Comment: Related: [optional dependencies in npm (on SE)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238257/optional-dependencies-in-npm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes, it's possible.

> What would the package.json and the GitHub organization look like?

The package should have the following structure:

```
- awesome-service
  - index.js       // main module
  - package.json   // package.json of the main package
  - http-service
    - index.js     // implementation of `http` service
    - package.json // package.json of `http` package
  - log-service
    - index.js     // implementation of `log` service
    - package.json // package.json of `log` package
```

As you see there are three `package.json` files. The root is used for main package, others for each service.

In each package.json, set `main` field to `index.js` and set a correct name for each package:

```
{
  "name": "awesome-service",
  "main": "index.js",
  ...
}

{
  "name": "awesome-service@http-service",
  "main": "index.js",
  ...
}

{
  "name": "awesome-service@log-service",
  "main": "index.js",
  ...
}
```

In `index.js` of the root package export the object with the fields - required services (I don't specify index.js in requires, because this module will be loaded by default):

```
module.exports = {
  httpService: require('./http-service'),
  logService: require('./log-service')
};
```

To use these three package separately, you should add all of them in npm, or use github with a proper url:

```
"dependencies": {
   "awesome-service": "awesome-service"
   "http-service": "awesome-service@http-service#1.0.0",
   "log-service": "git+https://github.com/yourAccount/awesome-service/log-service.git"
}
```

Comment: That's not what I asked for. This doesn't support importing individual "sub" services with different versions. i.e. I bump `log-service` and want to only update `log-service` and keep an older version of `http-service`